# Fix a Footer to the Bottom with html

Tags: html, css

I have my social media icons in the footer using html because nothing I tried with CSS gave me the results I wanted. Problem is that now I want the icons to be fixed to the bottom but doing it with CSS isn't working. Here's the code right now:

```
<div class="footer">
  <center>
    <a class="faceb" href="http://facebook.com/" title="Facebook" alt="faceb">
      <img src="http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wfaceb.png" hspace="5" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 20px" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/faceb.png'"onmouseout="this.src=' http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wfaceb.png'" border="0" alt="" />
    </a>
  </center>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS I tried that didn't work:

```
#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;   
}
```

Comment: You're using an ID selector for a class. Either replace the `#footer` with `.footer` or replace `class="footer"` with `id="footer"`

Comment: The `<center>` element is deprecated and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several issues with your original code. First you never close your `<center>` tag, but you should probably be using `text-align:center;` in your css instead as the center tag is depreciated.

Next you're using an ID selector instead of a class selector. So you have a couple options, you can either replace your CSS with:

```
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;   
}
```

Or you can replace your HTML with:

```
<div id="footer">
  <center>
    <a class="faceb" href="http://facebook.com/" title="Facebook" alt="faceb">
      <img src="http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wfaceb.png" hspace="5" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 20px" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/faceb.png'"onmouseout="this.src=' http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wfaceb.png'" border="0" alt="" />
    </a>
  </center>
</div>
```

---

But I'd highly recommend dropping those `center` tags and updating it like the following:

```
<div id="footer">
  <a class="faceb" href="http://facebook.com/" title="Facebook" alt="faceb">
    <img src="http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wfaceb.png" hspace="5" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 20px" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/faceb.png'"onmouseout="this.src=' http://www.sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wfaceb.png'" border="0" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

---

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: The `<center>` element is deprecated.

Comment: try adding: `margin: 0 auto;` to the CSS as well.

Comment: Also, if you would like the footer to always be visible, use `position:fixed;` instead. Also, `position:absolute` will break if the page needs to scroll.

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMwGzX) is a codepen that shows another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **id(#)** selector use **dot(.)** instead as you are using class in your div.

```
.footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:60px;   
}
```